# Filtering list from database without using java8 Stream

Tags: java

The given filtering condition is using the stream in JAVA 8 how do I change it without using stream. I have to filter the customer and employee commodities from the database in the controller

```
          else if
          ("Employee".equalsIgnoreCase(soption)) 
          { customerVOs = customerVOs.stream()
                    .filter( s-> s.getRole().equalsIgnoreCase("Employee"))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()); 
          }
        model.addAttribute("customerVOs", customerVOs);
```

Comment: You can use a loop.

Comment: There should be a DAO class or Spring Repository in your application responsible for retrieval of `customerVO` from the DB, and you should update the related method to return a filtered list.  Basically, a SQL request containing a `WHERE` clause should be built, so the data are filtered by the DB server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
customerVOs = customerVOs.stream()
                    .filter( s-> s.getRole().equalsIgnoreCase("Employee"))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Can be written without stream as below,

```
for(var s: customerVOs){ // loop over your list from db
  if(s.getRole().equalsIgnoreCase("Employee")){
   // TODO add in list here
  }
}
```

Comment: I did this but why is it not retuning any vallues in result
         result.add(customer.getEmail());
         result.add(customer.getGender());
         result.add(customer.getMobile());
         result.add(customer.getEmail());
         result.add(customer.getRole());

Comment: @hxg2100 can you add your new code in question?